# Asking user for home address using Regex

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, street-address

I want to make a prompt asking a user for a valid home address using regex.

I have tested the regex im using on regex101.com but the code still doesnt work no matter what I write...

Example of address that should pass: 26 John Street, City Road

What have I done wrong?

function button1() {
let address = prompt("Please enter your address");
var regex = /[\d+[ ](?:[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[ ]?)+(?:Avenue|Lane|Road|Boulevard|Drive|Street|Ave|Dr|Rd|Blvd|Ln|St).?]/;

```
  if (regex.test(address)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log("Please enter a valid address");
    return false;

  }
}
```

Comment: *"What have I done wrong?"* All due respect, what you've done wrong is assume addresses fit a specific format. They don't. An address can be just about anything. Simply ensure that the user filled something in, and that's it. Otherwise, you ***will*** prevent someone from providing their correct address. (Heck, as far as I can tell, the above doesn't even allow apartment numbers, much less things like space numbers in mobile home parks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I think you shouldn't have the whole expression inside `[` and `]`

That causes it not to be a sequence of symbols to be expected one-after-the-other, but rather a set of alternatives (which I don't think is what you intended).

So try this:

```js
function button1() {
  //  let address = prompt("Please enter your address");
  const address = "26 John Street, City Road"

  var regex = /\d+[ ](?:[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[ ]?)+(?:Avenue|Lane|Road|Boulevard|Drive|Street|Ave|Dr|Rd|Blvd|Ln|St).?/;

  if (regex.test(address)) {
    console.log("Valid")
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log("Please enter a valid address");
    return false;

  }
}

button1()
```